# Github Actions CI/CD without docker on an -Django-Gunicorn-Nginx

Tags: django, github-actions, gunicorn, cicd

I have a digital ocean server setup with Django-Gunicorn-Nginx. Everything is working as expected but sadly every time I make a code change I have to manually login to my server, pull my changes from github and restart gunicorn. Is it possible to setup a CI/CD workflow by just using Github-Actions?

P.S - Docker is not an option right now.

Comment: I have the same problem